# Python : go backwards through a string, then remove everything after a specific character

Tags: python, string

I have a string, which after a character I wish to remove everything after the character. However, the issue is that I have multiple characters like this in the string and its only the characters after the last one which I wish to remove.

for example:

```
str = "howdie how are you? are you good? sdfsdf"
str = str.RemoveEverythingAfterLast("?")
str = "howdie how are you? are you good?"
```

I was wondering if there was an efficient way to do this in python? I had thought of looping backwards through the string deleting characters 1 by 1 until I found the character I was looking for (in example the '?'). But I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: by using `str` as name, you are overwriting built-in function, you should avoid that and use other name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str.rpartition()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
''.join(string.rpartition('?')[:2])
```

Demo:

```
>>> string = "howdie how are you? are you good? sdfsdf"
>>> ''.join(string.rpartition('?')[:2])
'howdie how are you? are you good?'
```

Comment: Looks from question like OP wants the question mark left on the output, btw.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: ah, adjusted.

Comment: returns empty string if separator is not in input string

Comment: @m.wasowski: which is easy enough to test for, of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters of course, or add `x if cond else y` expression inside join ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
str = re.sub("(.*\?).*", "\\1", str)
```

capturing the group till the last `?` and replace it with captured group `\\1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.rfind`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) and [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2555451):

```
>>> string = "howdie how are you? are you good? sdfsdf"
>>> string[:string.rfind("?") + 1]
'howdie how are you? are you good?'
>>>
```

The `+ 1` will cause the `?` to be left on the end of the returned string.

Comment: Great, didn't know about `rfind`. That simplifies a lot what I tried to do :)